# Check if MySQL configuration was applied

Tags: mysql, configuration, innodb

I'm performing some heavy MySQL operations at my VM and constantly getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1206 The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size

I googled that increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size` option in `my.cnf` may solve the issue. The only `my.conf` I found at my VM is located at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. There was no `innodb_buffer_pool_size` setting there at all so I added:

> innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G

and then increased it to 2G but still the error is there. After each altering of the `my.cnf` file I restarted my VM completely.

The question is if there any chance to check if `innodb_buffer_pool_size` parameter was taken into consideration and I'm modifying correct file?

My `my.cnf` has `root:root` owner but permissions are `-rw-r--r--` so I guess MySQL should be able to read it.

Comment: Have you made sure that the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is actually in the `[mysqld]` section of the configuration file and that the other `innodb_*` variables have sensible values too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is execute a query like this:

```
show variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'
```

which will give you the present value of that variable. (All configuration settings end up as system variables).

Check this out too: [show variables syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-variables.html).